# Compare current data with data of the a year ago, the same date (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to return the data of the orders of the current date and the orders of the same date a year ago. 
My idea was to create two similar tables and merge the date by adding WHERE clauses. But it seems to not work.
Could you have a look at my code and see if you identify something wrong?
My outcome of this is totally blank.
Thanks a lot!

```
 WITH 
orders_channels AS
(SELECT
    'BLH' AS brand,
    date_trunc('week', date)::date AS date,
    channel,
    order_type,
    case when (date_trunc('week', date)::date = current_date -  interval '1 day') then 'current' 
    else 'previous' end 
    as week_type,
    sum(orders) AS orders
FROM
    de_data.orders_daily_channel_attribution_dashboard 
WHERE
    date > date_trunc('day', current_date) - interval '1 day'

GROUP BY 1,2,3,4),

wow_orders_channels AS
(SELECT
    'BLH' AS brand,
    date_trunc('week', date)::date AS date,
    channel,
    order_type,
    case when (date_trunc('week', date)::date = current_date -  interval '1 day') then 'current' 
    else 'previous' end 
    as week_type,
    sum(orders) AS orders
FROM
    de_data.orders_daily_channel_attribution_dashboard 
WHERE
    date >= date_trunc('week', current_date) - INTERVAL '1 year'

GROUP BY 1,2,3,4)

SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
        o.brand,
        date_trunc('week', o.date)::date as week,
        'SEO_ACQ' AS name,
        o.orders,
        wow.orders as wow_orders

    FROM
        orders_channels o 
        join wow_orders_channels wow on wow.date = o.date - interval '1 year' and o.order_type = wow.order_type
       where
         o.channel = 'SEO'
         AND o.order_type = 'ACQUISITION'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        o.brand,
        date_trunc('week', o.date) as week,
        'CRM_ORDERS' AS name,
        SUM(o.orders),
        sum(wow.orders) as wow_orders
    FROM
        orders_channels o 
        join wow_orders_channels wow on wow.date = o.date - interval '1 year' and o.order_type = wow.order_type

    WHERE
         o.channel = 'CRM'
    GROUP BY 1,2,3) x
ORDER BY 3,2
```

Comment: How are you want to deal with leap years?

Comment: I haven't really thought about it. I am still struggling to make it work to the normal years :)

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you provide the schema of the relevant table(s), some sample data, and the output you would expect with that data.

Comment: Basic information is missing: Your Postgres version, the table definition. And `seems to not work` is neither a valid error message nor a helpful description of what's wrong. Please edit the question to clarify.